# How to Ensure Gallery Works on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery

I have this Gallery which I used from this link: https://codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/ELfzd

The issue is that it works on Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari but not Internet Explorer, I would like for it to work on Internet Explorer as well but I'm not sure how.

This  is a screen shot of what the non-working version look like. 
Non-Working Version - https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeGd7.jpg

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #534B56;
  /* Colour = Bossanova */
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Agency FB", "Atrament Web", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: xx-large;
  color: #FFFFFF/* Colour = White */
}


/* Navigation Bar */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #534B56;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

nav.hidden {
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#current a {
  color: #D0879B;
}


/* End of Navigation Bar */


/* Links */

a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: #ffffff;
  /* Colour = White */
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Agency FB", "Atrament Web", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 19px
}

a:hover {
  color: #D0879B;
  /* Colour = Can Can */
}


/* End of Links */


/* Header */

div.Content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 56%;
  left: 42%;
  font-family: "Agency FB", "Atrament Web", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: xx-large;
  color: #FFFFFF/* Colour = White */
}


/* End of Header */


/* Back to Top Button */

#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: 99;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* End of Back to Top Button */


/* Gallery CSS */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery {
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.gallery>div>a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

.gallery>div>a>img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  transition: .1s transform;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  /* hack */
}

.gallery>div:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

.gallery>div:hover>a>img {
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transition: .3s transform;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

h1 {
  margin: 40px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
}

div.Footer {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 130%;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

div.Footer p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Agency FB", "Atrament Web", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.Footer_Menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

li.Footer_Items {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

li.Footer_Items a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

li.Footer_Items a:hover {
  color: #D0879B;
}

img.Social_Media_Icons {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

a.imglink {
  display: inline-block;
}

a.imglink img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

a.imglink:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!-- Start of Navigation Bar -->
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li id="current"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<!-- End of Navigation Bar -->

<!-- Start of Javascript for Navigation Bar -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {

    var documentElem = $(document),
      nav = $('nav'),
      lastScrollTop = 0;

    documentElem.on('scroll', function() {
      var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

      //scroll down
      if (currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop) nav.addClass('hidden');
      //scroll up
      else nav.removeClass('hidden');

      lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
    });
  })();
</script>
<!-- End of Javascript for Navigation Menu -->

<br />

<br />

<h1>
  Gallery
</h1>

<!-- Start of Gallery -->
<div class="gallery cf">

  <!-- Images will display as a thumbnail and open in a new link as a larger image. -->

  <div>
    <a href="Images/Optimized/FullImage_1.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="Images/Optimized/Thumbnail_1.jpg" width="200" height="300" alt="Image 1" title="Click to See Larger Image" styles="" /></a>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="Images/Optimized/FullImage_2.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="Images/Optimized/Thumbnail_2.jpg" width="200" height="300" alt="Image 2" title="Click to See Larger Image" styles="" /></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="Images/Optimized/FullImage_3.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="Images/Optimized/Thumbnail_3.jpg" width="200" height="300" alt="Image 3" title="Click to See Larger Image" styles="" /></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="Images/Optimized/FullImage_4.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="Images/Optimized/Thumbnail_4.jpg" width="200" height="300" alt="Image 4" title="Click to See Larger Image" styles="" /></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="Images/Optimized/FullImage_5.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="Images/Optimized/Thumbnail_5.jpg" width="200" height="300" alt="Image 5" title="Click to See Larger Image" /></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="Images/Optimized/FullImage_6.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="Images/Optimized/Thumbnail_6.jpg" width="200" height="300" alt="Image 6" title="Click to See Larger Image" /></a>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- End of Gallery -->

<!-- Back to Top Button -->
<img src="Images/backtotop.png" alt="Back to Top" onClick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Click to go Back to Top" />
<!-- Back to Top Button -->

<!-- Back to Top Button Javascript -->
<script>
  // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
  window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction()
  };

  function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
      document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
  function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }
</script>


<!-- Footer -->

<div class="Footer">

  <!-- Start of Footer -->

  <!-- Footer Menu -->
  <ul class="Footer_Menu">
    <li class="Footer_Items"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="Footer_Items"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li class="Footer_Items"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="Footer_Items"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="Footer_Items"><a href="links.html">Links</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- End of Footer Menu -->

  <!-- Social Media Icons -->
  <center>
    <a class="imglink" href="https://www.facebook.com/FluffleSan/?ref=br_rs" target="_blank"><img class="Social_Media_Icons" src="Images/Footer_Facebook_Gallery.png" width="25" height="30" alt="Facebook Icon" title="Click to go to Facebook Page" /></a>

    &nbsp; &nbsp;

    <a class="imglink" href="flufflesan.tumblr.com" target="_blank"><img class="Social_Media_Icons" src="Images/Footer_Tumblr_Gallery.png" width="25" height="30" alt="Tumblr Icon" title="Click to go to Tumblr Blog" /></a>

    &nbsp; &nbsp;

    <a class="imglink" href="https://www.instagram.com/fluffle_san/" target="_blank"><img class="Social_Media_Icons" src="Images/Footer_Instagram_Gallery.png" width="25" height="30" alt="Instagram Icon" title="Click to go to Instagram Icon" /></a>

  </center>

  <!-- End of Social Media Icons -->

  <!-- Start of Copyright Notice -->
  <p> &copy; 2017 Rebecca Holden Graphic Design All Rights Reserved. </p>
  <!-- End of Copyright Notice -->

  <!-- End of Footer -->
</div>
```

Comment: if(IE) alert("please  use a modern browser!")

Comment: could you be a little bit more specific on what exactly "isn't working" in IE?

Comment: Sorry! This is a screen shot of the working version: http://imgur.com/a/WqZTa , there's colour, a navigational menu and images appearing in the gallery but for the Internet Explorer Version there's no colours and no images.

Comment: ok, good to know... cause your  snippet looks the same as your first example image

Comment: did you just copy the css from the codepen here!? if you want us to help you with your styling in IE you might want to include that styling...

Comment: Oh my gosh! I'm so sorry, I forgot to add my style sheet, so so sorry. I've updated the snippet now.

Comment: ha, it happens! i was just confused, i'm going to look over it now ;)